# Where to call NotificationCenter.default.addObserver() ? in my Xcode Game Project

Tags: xcode, notificationcenter

Where to call `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver()` ? in my Xcode Game Project

I successfully call the following from my `func application (AppDelegate)`, but when I toggle the Gamepad on/off, my selectors are **not** being called.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    func ObserveForGameControllers() {
        
    //  print("ObserveForGameControllers")
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                    self,
                    selector: #selector(connectControllers),
                    name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidConnect,
                    object: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                    self,
                    selector: #selector(disconnectControllers),
                    name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidDisconnect,
                    object: nil)
        
    }   // ObserveForGameControllers

}
```

My selectors look like this:

```
@objc func connectControllers() {}
@objc func disconnectControllers() {}
```

One last thing:

[Here are my Gamepad settings in my Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lidf.png)

It seems I really need some suggestions here.

Appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I have been in contact with a very talented **jrturton** on trying to discover why I am unable to detect the presence of my Gamepad as documented above.

He has asked for a more complete presentation of my Swift code. I initially thought of Dropbox, but he has asked for this EDIT .. so here goes:

I began with a **iOS Game Project** which presented me with `AppDelegate`, `GameScene`, `GameViewController` + `Storyboard`.

I’ve already covered `AppDelegate` above, which per **jrturton**’s recommendation is now reduced to the standard `AppDelegate` `func`’s which essentially are empty, such as:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
                 launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // currently empty

}
```

Next, the `GameScene` ..

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GameController


class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        
        super.sceneDidLoad()
        
    //  print("sceneDidLoad")
        
        ObserveForGameControllers()
        
    }   // sceneDidLoad


    func ObserveForGameControllers() {
        
    //  print("ObserveForGameControllers")
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                    self,
                    selector: #selector(connectControllers),
                    name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidConnect,
                    object: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                    self,
                    selector: #selector(disconnectControllers),
                    name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidDisconnect,
                    object: nil)
        
    }   // ObserveForGameControllers
    
    
    @objc func connectControllers() {
        
    //  print("CONNECT")

        self.isPaused = false
        
        var indexNumber = 0
        
        for controller in GCController.controllers() {
            
            if controller.extendedGamepad != nil {
                controller.playerIndex = GCControllerPlayerIndex.init(rawValue: indexNumber)!
                
                indexNumber += 1
                setupControllerControls(controller: controller)
            }
            
        }
        
    }   // connectControllers

    
    @objc func disconnectControllers() {
        
    //  print("DIS-CONNECT")

        self.isPaused = true
        
    }   // disconnectControllers
    

    func setupControllerControls(controller: GCController) {
        
        controller.extendedGamepad?.valueChangedHandler = {
            (gamepad: GCExtendedGamepad, element: GCControllerElement) in
            
            self.controllerInputDetected(gamepad: gamepad,
                                         element: element,
                                         index: controller.playerIndex.rawValue)
        }
        
    }   // setupControllerControls


    func controllerInputDetected(gamepad: GCExtendedGamepad,
                                 element: GCControllerElement,
                                 index: Int) {
        
        // A-Button
        if (gamepad.buttonA == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.buttonA.value != 0)
            {
                // These print(..) statements will be replaced later
                // by code to access my Javascript methods.
                print("movePaddleDown")
            }
        }
        
        // B-Button
        else if (gamepad.buttonB == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.buttonB.value != 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleRight")
            }
        }
        
        // Y-Button
        else if (gamepad.buttonY == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.buttonY.value != 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleUp")
            }
        }
        
        // X-Button
        else if (gamepad.buttonX == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.buttonX.value != 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleLeft")
            }
        }
        
        // leftShoulder
        else if (gamepad.leftShoulder == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.leftShoulder.value != 0)
            {
                print("cyclePages")
            }
        }
        
        // rightShoulder
        else if (gamepad.rightShoulder == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.rightShoulder.value != 0)
            {
                print("newGame")
            }
        }
        
        // leftTrigger
        else if (gamepad.leftTrigger == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.leftTrigger.value != 0)
            {
                print("pauseGame")
            }
        }
        
        // rightTrigger
        else if (gamepad.rightTrigger == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.rightTrigger.value != 0)
            {
                print("resumeGame")
            }
        }
        
        // Left Thumbstick
        else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.xAxis.value > 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleRight")
            }
            else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.xAxis.value < 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleLeft")
            }
            else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.xAxis.value == 0)
            {
                print("decreaseSpeed")
            }
            else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.yAxis.value > 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleDown")
            }
            else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.yAxis.value < 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleUp")
            }
            else if (gamepad.leftThumbstick.yAxis.value == 0)
            {
                print("decreaseSpeed")
            }
        }
        
        // Right Thumbstick
        if (gamepad.rightThumbstick == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.rightThumbstick.xAxis.value > 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleRight")
            }
            else if (gamepad.rightThumbstick.xAxis.value < 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleLeft")
            }
            else if (gamepad.rightThumbstick.xAxis.value == 0)
            {
                print("decreaseSpeed")
            }
            else if (gamepad.rightThumbstick.yAxis.value > 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleDown")
            }
            else if (gamepad.rightThumbstick.yAxis.value < 0)
            {
                print("movePaddleUp")
            }
            else if (gamepad.rightThumbstick.yAxis.value == 0)
            {
                print("decreaseSpeed")
            }
        }
        
        // D-Pad
        else if (gamepad.dpad == element)
        {
            if (gamepad.dpad.xAxis.value > 0)
            {
                print("scrollWindowRight")
            }
            else if (gamepad.dpad.xAxis.value < 0)
            {
                print("scrollWindowLeft")
            }
            else if (gamepad.dpad.yAxis.value > 0)
            {
                print("scrollWindowDown")
            }
            else if (gamepad.dpad.yAxis.value < 0)
            {
                print("scrollWindowUp")
            }
        }
        
    }   // controllerInputDetected

}   // class GameScene: SKScene
```

Now, the `GameViewController` ..

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import WebKit


// This is now available across Classes
var theWebView: WKWebView!


class GameViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    override func loadView() {
        
    //  print("loadView")
        
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        theWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        theWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = theWebView
        
    }   // loadView
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    //  print("viewDidLoad")
               
        loadURL(webAddress: "https://www.lovesongforever.com/firstgame")
        
    }   // viewDidLoad
    
    
    func loadURL(webAddress: String) {
        
        let theURL = URL(string: webAddress)
        let theRequest = URLRequest(url: theURL!)
        theWebView.load(theRequest)
        theWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false

    }   // loadURL

    
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        }
        else {
            return .all
        }
        
    }   // supportedInterfaceOrientations

    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        
        return true
        
    }   // prefersStatusBarHidden
    
}   // class GameViewController
```

Note that when I RUN my iOS App, thanks to the overridden `loadView()` above, it presents the following in the Simulator:

[Simulator presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H8RW.jpg)

But, that’s is as far as it goes, because pressing all the buttons on my Gamepad does **not** result in detection of my Gamepad, as evidenced when I UN-comment all the above print(..) statements.  In particular, those within:

`@objc func connectControllers()` and
`@objc func disconnectControllers()` and
`func controllerInputDetected( .. )`

So, hopefully that is all there currently is ..

Comment: Please show the code where you call `ObserveForGameControllers`. The app delegate seems a little early to be calling methods on a scene

Comment: `let itsGameScene = GameScene();`
`itsGameScene.ObserveForGameControllers()`

Comment: FWIW, I agree on your early comment ... but I don't know of an alternative. I thought of `class GameViewController`, but I am far from certain.

Comment: The code you've added doesn't load any SKScene, it just creates and opens a web view. The screenshot you've attached is from a web page. Are you making a [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit) game, or wrapping a web page game in an iOS app?

Comment: Trying to wrap a web page game in an iOS app. Sounds a bunch easier than building a game from scratch. I just don’t understand why calling up a WKWebView within gameViewController’s viewDidLoad isn’t reacting to my Gamepad. My screenshot says it’s there, but zero reaction yo the Gamepad

Comment: BTW I can’t use my webpage Game totally because it uses the Gamepad API which calls waitForGamepadIsConnected/Disconnected. Clearly Sprite doesn’t understand this. So I must use Sprite to detect Gamepad

Comment: My existing Web Game is at: lovesongforever.com/firstgame. The basic reason for trying to convert to iOS app is because folk would rather tap on a iOS App than insert a http address into a Browser. Besides, this becomes a reason to get back into Xcode. Was 15 years ago in the days of IBOutlet.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that won't fly on the App Store, but that doesn't stop you making this as a technical exercise. I've updated my answer which, if it gets you seeing those connection messages, I think should close off this question. It's been a journey :D

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in your app delegate:

```swift
let itsGameScene = GameScene() 
itsGameScene.ObserveForGameControllers()
```

You're creating an instance of `GameScene`, making it listen for notifications (adding `self` as the observer)... and then probably throwing that instance away.

Your game isn't actually using `SpriteKit`, and `SpriteKit` isn't needed to deal with game controllers, you just need `GameController`.

You have no need to create this scene at all. The best place to observe the game controller notifications would be in your `GameViewController` in `viewDidLoad`. Move the code (the observation method and the controller-related ones) you had in your scene into the view controller, and delete the scene file.